# Replace a range of numbers with different range of numbers in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, insert-update

For example replace

```
TransactionID
--------
 1
 2
 3
```

with

```
TransactionID
--------
 95
 96
 97
```

respectively. Basically, I want to replace numbers with numbers but for multiple items without writing update statement for each item.

Example:

```
Update BatchItem
    set TransactionID = '95'
    where BatchItemID = 12345**6**


Update BatchItem
    set TransactionID = '96'
    where BatchItemID = 12345**7**


Update BatchItem
    set TransactionID = '97'
    where BatchItemID = 12345**8**
```

How do I write above statement to update multiple transactionID in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to do something like this?

```
declare @offset int
set @offset = 94

update BatchItem
    set TransactionID = TransactionID + @offset
    where BatchItemID = 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE BatchItem SET TransactionId = TransactionId + 94
```

**UPDATE**

This appears to be the "quick and dirty" version of @Joe's answer.  I'll leave it up in case you find it less confusing than his answer...

Comment: Are you saying I confuse people? :-)

Comment: Abe, yours SQL statement does make sense, but it does not do my job. I think your statement does give me an idea. Actually, I am doing find and replace in SQL transactionID and all transactionID are in sequence.